# Conditional/Occasional Logging with Boost Log Library

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a way to do Conditional/Occasional logging with Boost Log Library? For example, log a message at every Nth passing the logging statement.

P.S. [Google Logging Library](https://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html) has those functions/macros: `LOG_EVERY_N`, `LOG_IF`, `LOG_FIRST_N`. But I need a library that works in Mingw-w64 (Google Logging Library is not).

Answer (score 0):

Boost Log gives you the possibility to filter your logs by adding filters to the sinks, see:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/advanced_filtering.html

So you can for example add tags to specific logs and then write your filter logic based on those tags.